# JS async function keeps running even after I returned result. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, botkit-4

I'm trying to customize a Slack Bot with Botkit for exercise but I ran into a problem and I can't seem to figure it out. I want to retrieve a random post from Reddit, check if it's an image and then return it if it is, otherwise get another post. Now, I'm not that familiar with async/await functions, I read a few docs about it, but looks like I'm still not getting something right here. Can someone point me in the right direction?

So in my script I have this:

```
const reddit = require( '../app/reddit' )

module.exports = function(controller) {
    controller.hears( 'test123', 'message,direct_message', async ( bot, message ) => {
        let image = await reddit.get_random_image()
        console.log(image)
    } )
}
```

And also this:

```
const get_random_image = async () => {

    let posts = await wrap.getHot( 'memes', { limit: 100 } )

    const post = fn.get_random_array_item( posts )

    if ( post.url.indexOf('.jpg') !== -1 || post.url.indexOf('.png') !== -1 || post.url.indexOf('.gif') !== -1 ) {
        console.log('image')
        return Promise.resolve( '*' + post.title + '* ( /' + post.subreddit_name_prefixed + ' )\n' + post.url )
    } else {
        console.log('not an image')
        return await get_random_image()
    }

}
module.exports.get_random_image = get_random_image
```

What happens is, when I write 'test123' in Slack, the function runs and it the first post is indeed an image everything seems fine and code stops, but if first post is not an image and function calls itself again it runs over and over again for some time, even when image is encountered.

Edit:

Added screenshots of console.
This happends if first selected post is not an image:
[image: This happends when first selected post is not an image]

And this happends when it is an image:
[image: And this happends when it is an image]

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce that behavior. Are you sure there is no more code involved? Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yehud056/) It's working fine. Also, async already returns a promise, so no need to return `Promise.resolve('response')` you can just `return 'response'`, also `return await` is not needed, you can just `return get_random_image()`

Comment: @AleSanchez tried your suggestions but the problem still persists. I added some screenshots of console in original post

Comment: Who is printing the "run" message?

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it with only async functions](https://jsbin.com/gipovixoli/1/edit?js,console). This suggests that whatever happens is because of the bot code.

Comment: @AleSanchez ah sorry, I added console.log('run') to get_random_image function to see when it's being called

Comment: I would suggest debugging (or adding a console.log) to the arrow function defined as a parameter of `hears` function to see if that is being called more than once. Because none of us has been able to reproduce it out of the box

Comment: @AleSanchez did that, seems like function inside hears runs multiple times after I type the keyword... tried the same thing with different keyword and different function inside 'hears' that just types out a reply in Slack and that runs fine, 1 time